# how to add a cta button to a live stream post through the facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to add a CTA button to my Facebook video live stream post.

After starting the live broadcast, I request this API interface

https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/<FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID>/feed

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "108412001777497_269384965974520",
            "story": "花迪-珠宝正在直播视频",
            "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/245662590014980/videos/<VIDEO_ID>",
            "full_picture": "https://scontent-hkg4-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/....",
            "status_type": "added_video",
            "is_expired": false,
            "is_hidden": false,
            "is_published": true,
            "is_eligible_for_promotion": true,
            "promotable_id": "108412001777497_269384965974520",
            "is_instagram_eligible": false,
            "instagram_eligibility": "ineligible_unknown_error",
            "created_time": "2023-09-07T11:11:53+0000",
            "updated_time": "2023-09-07T11:11:53+0000"
        },
        // ....
    ]
}
```

I tried to call the interface for updating the video to add the CTA button, but it failed. The error message means that editing through the video API is not possible during live streaming.

Request

POST https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/<VIDEO_ID>

```json
{
    "call_to_action": {
        "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
        "value": {
            "link_format": "VIDEO_LPP"
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Service temporarily unavailable",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "is_transient": false,
        "code": 2,
        "error_subcode": 1969005,
        "error_user_title": "Editing via the Video API is not possible during a live stream",
        "error_user_msg": "Live video cannot be edited using the video editing API. Please use the live video number to edit.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AXWbR3pDK9VEdP9q9AwZWWL"
    }
}
```

According to the error message, it is recommended to use the live_video API for editing, but the call_to_action option is not provided in the live_video update API.

So, does anyone know how to dynamically add a CTA button to a Facebook Page Live Video via the API?

Comment: I directly used the Facebook ad management backend page to create an ad, selected the live broadcast, and added a CTA button. Then I called the API interface to get the updates under the public homepage again. I found that the video updates were updated success.

`
        {
            "id": "108412001777497_269384965974520",
            // ,,,
            "call_to_action": {
                "type": "MESSAGE_PAGE",
                "value": {
                    "link_format": "VIDEO_LPP"
                }
            }
        },
`